# In react-native, how can I make a View's background color change to another color, and then fade out?

Tags: react-native, animation, view

I'd like the View to change to dark blue, and then slowly fade back to normal (aka white).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **animated** by react-native.
 Here's a sample code to achieve what you are looking for

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      colorAnimation: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { colorAnimation } = this.state;

    {
      /* Change Color To blue */
    }
    Animated.timing(colorAnimation, {
      toValue: 255,
      duration: 1000 //Animation Duration
    }).start();

    {
      /*  After 1 second change color back to white */
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      Animated.timing(colorAnimation, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 3000 //Animation Duration
      }).start();
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    const interpolatedColor = this.state.colorAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 255],
      outputRange: ["rgb(255,255,255)", "rgb(0, 0, 139)"]
    });
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: interpolatedColor }]}
      ></Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 8
  }
});
```

[You can view the demo here.](https://snack.expo.io/HkPsaV4MB)